# How to replicate kdeplot's shade in a violinplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to replicate seaborn's kdeplot `shade=True` display on a violin plot.

[image]

However, `sns.violinplot()` does not take the `shade` argument. I can access the axis collection in the violinplot using `ax.collections[0]` and then use both `set_facecolor()` and `set_edgecolor()` to change the plot colors. However, I'm not sure how to give an alpha value to the facecolor of the plot. I can use `set_alpha()` but that sets the alpha for both the face and the edge colors.

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib accepts RGBA colors, e.g. `(1,0,0,0.5)` is half-transparent red

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, that's useful. What would be the best approach to convert HEX or RGB (0-255) values to RGB values between 0 an 1? I get an error when trying to put RGB values larger than 1.

Comment: Matplotlib uses RGB between 0 and 1. If you have values between 0 and 255 you can divide them by 255.

Comment: Wow, lets forget I asked that. But thanks!